# Mac using Virtual Box ubuntu, copy and paste doesnt work

Tags: virtual-machine, clipboard

I'm using macOS Moneterey Version 12.6.6 and VirtualBox Ubuntu.

I checked the boxes in Setting->General->Advanced, Shared clipboard and Drag'n'drop but the copy paste still doesnt work.

Is there something I'm missing?